# Libgdx - android version crashes when another screen initializes variables

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I'm trying out Libgdx by making a simple game. The desktop version runs great, though I'm having some issues with the android version.

The first screen (MainMenu) works great. No problems here.

However when the second screen(Game) calls the method show() and initializes the spritebatch, camera, etc. it crashes, even though its show() method is identical to first screen's show() method.

```
public void show() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sr = new ShapeRenderer();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

For example, these first three lines immediately causes the android version to crash. It doesn't help to give the variables unique names either.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Logcat:

```
04-29 06:53:10.450: I/dalvikvm(915): Debugger is active
04-29 06:53:10.500: I/System.out(915): Debugger has connected
04-29 06:53:10.500: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:10.710: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:10.920: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:11.120: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:11.330: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:11.530: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:11.730: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:11.940: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:12.140: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:12.340: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:12.540: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:12.740: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:12.940: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:13.150: I/System.out(915): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 06:53:13.390: I/System.out(915): debugger has settled (1339)
04-29 06:53:13.820: D/dalvikvm(915): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.me.game-1/libgdx.so 0xb3dc7ab8
04-29 06:53:13.820: D/dalvikvm(915): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.me.game-1/libgdx.so 0xb3dc7ab8
04-29 06:53:13.830: D/dalvikvm(915): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.me.game-1/libgdx.so 0xb3dc7ab8, skipping init
04-29 06:53:14.820: I/AndroidInput(915): sensor listener setup
04-29 06:53:15.330: I/Choreographer(915): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 06:53:15.590: D/gralloc_goldfish(915): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-29 06:53:15.650: I/AndroidGraphics(915): OGL renderer: Android PixelFlinger 1.4
04-29 06:53:15.650: I/AndroidGraphics(915): OGL vendor: Android
04-29 06:53:15.660: I/AndroidGraphics(915): OGL version: OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
04-29 06:53:15.660: I/AndroidGraphics(915): OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
04-29 06:53:15.660: I/AndroidGraphics(915): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
04-29 06:53:15.660: I/AndroidGraphics(915): depthbuffer: (16)
04-29 06:53:15.670: I/AndroidGraphics(915): stencilbuffer: (0)
04-29 06:53:15.680: I/AndroidGraphics(915): samples: (0)
04-29 06:53:15.680: I/AndroidGraphics(915): coverage sampling: (false)
04-29 06:53:15.740: I/AndroidGraphics(915): Managed meshes/app: { }
04-29 06:53:15.740: I/AndroidGraphics(915): Managed textures/app: { }
04-29 06:53:15.760: I/AndroidGraphics(915): Managed shaders/app: { }
04-29 06:53:15.760: I/AndroidGraphics(915): Managed buffers/app: { }
04-29 06:53:16.430: D/dalvikvm(915): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 6% free 3113K/3292K, paused 214ms, total 220ms
04-29 06:53:17.070: I/ARMAssembler(915): generated scanline__00000177:03545444_00001001_00000000 [ 94 ipp] (146 ins) at [0xaa8f41f0:0xaa8f4438] in 10000000 ns
04-29 06:53:17.290: I/ARMAssembler(915): generated scanline__00000177:03010144_00000000_00000000 [ 26 ipp] (63 ins) at [0xaa8f4440:0xaa8f453c] in 0 ns
04-29 06:53:22.620: I/System.out(915): hit
```

Comment: Stacktrace of the crash please.

Comment: Maybe you are creating too many spriteBatches and ShapeRenderers ,these objects require good amounts of memory and ofcourse when you run it on android there is less heap space,without the stacktrace and with the provided code ,this is the only assumption we can do.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. The crash only occurs when new stuff is initialized  . If the batch is passed on from the previous screen, it doesn't cause a crash. However, it would be a bit troublesome to pass on every single thing to the new screen. 

Oh, and I added the info provided by LogCat.

Comment: There should be an exception in your stack trace with a list of the classes and lines that were entered. I'm not sure where you got the above from.

Comment: Probably the debugger/logger.